# Pandas: handling MANY columns with mixed types

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to read a csv with 80,000 columns and there is no way i can specify the dtypes for all columns. Many of the columns contain timestamp and NaN, which generates the warnings message below.

`DtypeWarning: Columns have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`

An example column would look like this:

```
0       2021-01-04 09:51:03.167
1                           NaN
2       2021-01-04 11:23:11.978
3                           NaN
4                           NaN
          
1123    2021-08-31 14:14:21.159
1124                        NaN
1125                        NaN
1126    2021-08-31 16:09:13.939
1127    2021-08-31 16:09:13.939
```

I looked at this [link](https://www.roelpeters.be/solved-dtypewarning-columns-have-mixed-types-specify-dtype-option-on-import-or-set-low-memory-in-pandas/). But problem is I have so many columns with the same issue and there is no way I can specify a converter for them all. So how should I handle this in an efficient manner?

Comment: try `dict(df.dtypes)` I think it will give the data type of each column unlike `df.info()`, which just gives overall statistics.

Comment: Do you really need all 80k columns?